# add a button in pageBuilder.view to scroll between screens

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-animation

[this is the personal info screen and i wan to add the button  to the CvMakerScreen to be visibale for all sccreens in the list when i m scrolling between them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzzWV.png)
how can i add a button for pageview.builder to scroll between screens in list.
and how to make this button in bottom of the screen .
i havce already try to use the stack widjet but it doesn t give me the contol for the button position.
and if i use the widget positioned the button go to center of page if i open the phone keybord.

```
class CVMakerScreene extends StatefulWidget {

   CVMakerScreene({Key? key, }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CVMakerScreeneState createState() => _CVMakerScreeneState();
}
class _CVMakerScreeneState extends State<CVMakerScreene> {
  Color mainColor = Color(0xFF252c4a);
  PageController? controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  List<Widget> screens = [
    PersonalInfoScreene(),
    PortfolioScreene(),
    HomeLayout(),
    test()
  ];
  List<String> text = [
    'hi',
    'hello',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leadingWidth: 150,
        leading: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 15,),
              Text(
                'CV Maker',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,


                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: mainColor,
      ),
      body:
         PageView.builder(
             physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() ,
             controller: controller,
             itemCount: screens.length,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {

               return screens[index];
             }
         ),







    );
  }
}
```

Comment: After reading your question more than once I am still unsure what you’re asking.

Comment: I want to make a button to scroll between screns in pageview.builder. but i cant add cause pageview.builder can contien only on screen and u can look for the code to understand what i mean .i want to find the widjet who can work like a column between the screens in list and the button.and thx